# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax fix this

Tags: php, mysql

```html
CREATE FUNCTION wowdiscu_root.CreateGroup(GroupName VARCHAR(50), GroupIcon TEXT, GroupDescription VARCHAR(130), GroupCreator INT)
  RETURNS int(11)
  DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE groupID INT;
  INSERT INTO groups (name, icon, description) VALUES (GroupName, GroupIcon, GroupDescription);
  SET groupID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  INSERT INTO group_members VALUES (groupID, GroupCreator);
  RETURN groupID;
END;
```

MySQL said

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

can someone correct the above MySQL code?

Comment: Do you have a `delimiter` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a **delimiter**.

```
DELIMITER $ -- set delimiter to $
CREATE FUNCTION wowdiscu_root.CreateGroup(GroupName VARCHAR(50), GroupIcon TEXT, GroupDescription VARCHAR(130), GroupCreator INT)
  RETURNS int(11)
  DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE groupID INT;
  INSERT INTO groups (name, icon, description) VALUES (GroupName, GroupIcon, GroupDescription);
  SET groupID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  INSERT INTO group_members VALUES (groupID, GroupCreator);
  RETURN groupID;
END$

DELIMITER ; -- set delimiter back to ;
```